# How to install Vim scripts / plugins using viper-mode in emacs

Tags: vim, plugins, emacs, latex, viper-mode

I'm using viper-mode in emacs, and I'd like to use the [Vim-LaTeX plugin](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/index.php) with it.

How do I install the plugin to use in viper-mode?

Comment: Haha, I decided that it's better if I just choose pure vim or emacs, so I can get all the functionality of it (scripts and such). I chose vim :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, viper mode is an emulation of common vim functionality in emacs. It is not an implementation of vim. Therefore, I don't think it has the ability to use vim's plugins. A quick perusal of the [source code](http://repo.or.cz/w/emacs.git/blob/HEAD:/lisp/emulation/viper.el) doesn't seem to show any signs either. You may just have to break down and use vim :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the Emacs equivalent of that plugin, which in the case of vim-latex is probably [AUCTeX](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/).